# Cant remove space button from keybord in JtextField

Tags: java, textfield

I want to limit user to input a space in textfield. Can I remove specific keyboard button to be pressed in my app?? Thanks

Comment: This link should help ...http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/199116-prevent-user-from-typing-a-space-in-jtextfield/

Comment: You could use a `JFormattedTextField` along with a `javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is get the String without space you can use:

```
String str = "The string from textfield with space";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Also if you would block the space insert event you can use the input listener and from it disable/block the space.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm new in Java and improve

Answer (score -1):

Just use an if-statement to find out whether space got pressed and then remove the space!

Comment: Will not work, when the user copy-pastes strings containing spaces into the text field.

Comment: then you could just remove every space from the String using replace method

Comment: Where do you intend to put the if-statement. Inside a KeyListener, DocumentListener, etc?

Comment: I am not quite shure where to put it, cause the question is not asked clear enough. @John Terry JQ could you pls specify what your proplem actually is.

Comment: I believe, what he wants is a text field, into which spaces cannot be entered. Thus, the user can type text as usual, except that when the space button is pressed, nothing happens. This restriction, of course, includes, that the user cannot copy-paste spaces into the text field. This is what I was trying to hint at.